# I get Undefind from servlet respons value

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlet-3.0

**my script in jsp page**

```
        var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
        function clock()
        {
            $.get('all_acc', function(responseText) {
                    document.getElementById("acc_read").innerHTML = responseText.value;
                    });
        }
</script>
```

**Servlet class**

```
 @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        DataBase.database e=new database();
         Product.Company_Product cp=new Company_Product();
        try {
            x =e.get_all_acc();
            xx=""+x;
            System.out.println("sdsdsad asd      "+x);
    
  
            //response.setIntHeader("Site", x);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(all_acc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
     response.setContentType("text/jsp;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.write(xx);
    out.close();
  
        
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
       
        
       
    }
```

Comment: You should describe the problem a bit better not only post code out of context. This will make it easier for people to help you. In particular you should also describe your error message correctly (not only very briefly in the title).

Comment: Hi why do you have `responseText.value` ? why not simply have `responseText` ?Also what is `text/jsp` ? isn't that should be `text/html` or `text/plain` because you are simply returning text ?

Comment: I did that but i get  this : Servlet all_acc at /Bank_Web_App

Comment: Check you server logs there might be some error .Also ,check browser console has any errors.

Comment: server logs no error but browser console have this : 
Error: <svg> attribute height: Expected length, "undefined".
VectorCanvas.setSize @ jquery.vmap.min.js:10
jquery.vmap.min.js:10 Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "scale(NaN) translate(N…".

Comment: And This : 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at new Sparkline (sparkline.js:28)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard.js:92)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Hi ,is this `acc_read` id exist in your dom ? Also you need to put your jquery code after the htmls or after that `acc_read` div ,Also you are getting `404` error is your path right ?

Comment: Yes , acc_read div is before jquery code